# Route does not exist on the browser but it works fine on the postman

Tags: node.js, express, browser, routes, postman

Okay so i just started building an api using Node. Normally, before i even start, i test it in the postman using dummy data to make sure all the routes are working fine but i never tested it on the browser until today. It brings out the dummy data all fine in the postman but when I put in the same route i used in the postman on the browser tab, it just brings out my custom error message "Route does not exist". Why is this happening?

This is my routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const {upload} = require('../utils/multer')
const { register, login } = require('../controllers/auth')

router.post('/register', upload.single('picture'), register)
router.post('/login', login)

module.exports = router
```

This is my controllers/auth.js:

```
const register = async (req, res) => {
    res.send('register')
}

const login = async (req, res) => {
    res.send('login')
}

module.exports = {register, login}
```

This is my app.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
require('express-async-errors');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const multer = require('multer')
const helmet = require('helmet')  //helps you secure your Express apps by setting various HTTP headers.
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')


const express = require('express');
const app = express();



/* CONFIGURATIONS */
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/assets")));



//routers
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')



// error handlers
const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middleware/not-found');
const errorHandlerMiddleware = require('./middleware/error-handler');



//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());



//routes
app.use('/api/v1/auth', authRouter)



//errors
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);


//database
const connectDB = require('./db/connect');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

Please note that i do not understand what most of these configurations do, not very well anyways. i have tried to remove them though but the problem was still there.

Comment: Because your app is build only for handleling POST request from client side, Postman will work when you set on POST method, however you don't have any GET route to get access on the browser, btw you can uninstall Body-Parser, and remove the bodyparser middleware, since express can now handle it himself and you have already set the middleware on your app ( app.use(express.json()); )

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to access `/login` or `/register` route from browser search bar something like this `http://host:port/login`. With this browser will send `GET /login` request but `/login` is a POST method route that is the reason you are getting `Route not found`

Answer (score 0):

When you send request from your browser then by default it will send GET request and your app is not handling GET requests.

You are handling POST requests for `/register` and `/login` routes.